# Login to newsgroup with thunderbird3.0B2 for newsgroup that don't require login

Tags: thunderbird, login, newsgroups

I am trying to login to newsgroup(qt-interest) with thunderbird3.0B2.

The problem is that the newsgroup allows users to read messages without password, but require a password to post a message.

But because Thunderbird can read messages without a password, it don't ask me for login information which make it impossible to post in the newsgroup.

So where do I enter login/password for a newsgroup with thunderbird3.0B2

Comment: Belongs to     SU.

Answer (score 2):

Account Settings > Server Settings > "Always request authentication when connecting" (Check Mark)